# Issues about installing PCL in my computer

Tags: python, cython

When I try to install python-pcl(PCL is the point cloud library for presentation like laser radar data. I followed the instruction on https://github.com/strawlab/python-pcl ,and I have already copied travis/pcl-2d-1.8.pc file to /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig folder) in my computer. I typed `AppledeMacBook-Pro-3:python-pcl-0.3.0rc1 apple$ python setup.py install` in my terminal.Then I encountered a problem below:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to python_pcl.egg-info/requires.txt
writing python_pcl.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to python_pcl.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to python_pcl.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'python_pcl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'python_pcl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
skipping 'pcl/_pcl_180.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'pcl._pcl' extension
/usr/bin/clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/apple/miniconda3/include -I/Users/apple/miniconda3/include -DEIGEN_YES_I_KNOW_SPARSE_MODULE_IS_NOT_STABLE_YET=1 -I/Users/apple/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.4-h8f450c2_22/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/pcl-1.8 -I/usr/local/Cellar/openni/1.5.7.10/include/ni -I/usr/local/include/pcl-1.8 -I/usr/local/Cellar/flann/1.9.1_6/include -I/usr/local/include/pcl-1.8 -I/opt/local/include/eigen3 -I/usr/include/ni -I/usr/include/vtk-5.8 -I/usr/local/include/vtk-8.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/vtk/8.0.1/include -I/Users/apple/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.4-h8f450c2_22/include/python3.5m -c pcl/_pcl_180.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pcl/_pcl_180.o
warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-std=libc++' on the
      command line to use the libc++ standard library instead
      [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
pcl/_pcl_180.cpp:447:10: fatal error: 'vector' file not found
#include <vector>
         ^~~~~~~~
```

Somebody says it has something to do with my Cython version. But I have already switched Cython to version 0.25.2, still not working. Does anyone have the same problem? Many thanks. By the way, my python version is 3.5.4 and my Mac Version is macOS Mojave 10.14.1

Comment: Could you give us more details? What is pcl? What is the command you ran to try to install it? Where does this error message come from? (give us the full stack otherwise it is hard to help without context)

Comment: Sorry I added more details.

Comment: as ead mentioned, you'll need to tweak the setup manually, if an issue has not already been raise on their github tracker, you should also notify them

Comment: I will. Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: @LeeDennis Do you know, what a chameleon question is? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions  If you encounter a new problem ask a new question.

Comment: Oh sorry I am new to that. I will delete it and ask another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a special issue with current MacOS-installations. You could tweak `setup.py` and add, as the warning suggest, `-std=libc++` to the compile-options, i.e.

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

...  some stuff

#passing `-stdlib=libc++` to compiler and linker:
ext_modules = [Extension(...,
                         language='c++',
                         extra_compile_args=["-stdlib=libc++"], # + anything else you need
                         extra_link_args= ["-stdlib=libc++"] # + anything else you need]

... some more stuff
```

I have also added `-stdlib=libc++` to the linker options, because it will be probably the next problem you will run into.

More background: In the MacOS world, for long time, there where two different implementations of c++'s standard library: `-libstdc++` associated with `gcc` and `libc++` associated with `clang`. At the beginning`-libstdc++` was also used per default with `clang`-compiler. However, this is no longer the case - it is not even installed now and that is the reason why the headers cannot be found. I'm not sure why your `clang`-version doesn't take `libc++` per default - so you have to pass it manually to compiler/linker.